Unable to locate any package, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
I have used
'''sudo apt update'''
'''sudo apt upgrade'''
But I can't install literally any app not even gparted someone help me
Btw I'm a beginner to PC's and Ubuntu please tell me in detail

Please read the info on this link and edit your question. As written there is no info here that can be used to offer any help. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Your details imply you've not been applying security and other fixes to your system for some time, ie. a fully upgraded 22.04 system has reported itself as 22.04.4 since February 2024 (before the ISO release date in my link actually) so this isn't a new situation I gather...   Start by running sudo apt update & read the messages, warnings & look out for missing lines...  You've not provided that detail in your question, thus we can't pick what is wrong.. alternatively you can explore your sources & look for issues there

If you need help, add that detail to your question (either paste it to your question, or paste online using pastebinit or other tool) and we can help you with it... We're limited to details you provide; which tell me you've had an issue since Feb 2024 & its either not running sudo apt update, or corrupted sources which you'll detect by reading the output (or lack of output!!) of that command and then subsequent fixes like sudo apt -f install....  If you added an inappropriate source/package to your system, you need to fix it as problems remain.

Does this answer your question? How do I restore the default repositories?
